# In flask-stormpath, how do I route a user to a specific page after loging in based on the user's Stormpath group

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, stormpath

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

I'm working on a flask app that uses Stormpath for authentication. In my app I have two user groups: `normal users` and `admins`. After a user logs in, I'd like to redirect them to a specific page based on the group they belong to. So if a user is a normal user they'd be redirected to `/dashboard` and if they are an admin, they'd be redirected to `/admin_dashboard`. As of right now, I have `STORMPATH_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard'` so every time they log in they get redirected to `/dashboard` regardless of the group they belong to. **How can I redirect them to a specific page based on their Stormpath group?**

**CURRENT CODE SNIPPETS:**

Note: I am using the default Flask-Stormpath login views and the app allows social login through Google.

`/app/__init__.py:`

```
def create_app(config_name):
  ...
  # App config here
  ...
  stormpath_manager = StormpathManager()
  stormpath_manager.init_app(app)
  ...
  return app
```

`/config.py:`

```
class Config(Object):
  ...
  STORMPATH_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard'
  ...
```

`/app/dashboard/views.py:`

```
@dashboard_blueprint.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
@groups_required(['normal-users'])
def dashboard():
  return render_template('dashboard/index.html', title="Dashboard")

@dashboard_blueprint.route('/admin_dashboard')
@login_required
@groups_required(['admins'])
def admin_dashboard():
  return render_template('dashboard/admin_index.html', title="Admin Dashboard")
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to include your current code? The Flask views and how you are using Stormpath.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren Please see edited question for requested info. Let me know if any other info is necessary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

flask_stormpath has a `User` class as seen [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-flask/blob/master/flask_stormpath/models.py), which takes in an `Account` as an argument. From the `stormpath-sdk-python`, we can see that an `Account` has a `has_group(self, resolvable)` function as seen [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-python/blob/master/stormpath/resources/account.py#L209).

So to display a specific page after a user logs in, based on the group the user belongs to, I made the following changes to `/app/dashboard/views.py` while keeping the others unchanged:

```
from flask_stormpath import User
from flask_stormpath import current_user

@dashboard_blueprint.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
  if User.has_group(current_user, 'normal-users'):
    return render_template('dashboard/index.html', title="Dashboard")
  elif User.has_group(current_user, 'admins'):
    return render_template('dashboard/admin_index.html', title="Admin Dashboard")
  else:
      return render_template('dashboard/error.html', title="Error Page")
```